# How do I get python to run in visualStudioCode MacOS

Tags: python

I would like to run python 2.17 on my Mac through VisualStudioCode. However I keep getting this error message. Any idea why?

I have tried copying the code to a new file and restarting VCS.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Home/Documents/_Sue IT Polytech 2019/Software Development/LinkedInPyTutOct2019/Exercise Files/Chap03/03_05_begin.py", line 2, in <module>
    name = input("What's your name? ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Sue' is not defined
Suzannes-MBP:Exercise Files Home$
```

Expected output was the program to continue with the task. The program asks a name, one is given and then a 'detailed' message is supposed to appear.

Comment: In Python 2, use `raw_input` instead of `input`. However, I **highly** recommend using Python 3, not Python 2.

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you're using Python 2.x.

Use **raw_input** instead of **input** to get string from user.